# How to grep n lines from the first occurence of a string in linux?

Tags: grep

I need to share logs to developers. They keep asking for more logs. So, I'm wondering is there a way to grep 1000 or so lines after the first occurence of a string in linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want the `-A` option: from the man page:

> Context Line Control
>
> ```
>    -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
>           Print  NUM  lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing a
>           group  separator  (--)  between  contiguous  groups  of  matches.   With  the   -o   or
>           --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
>
>    -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
>           Print  NUM  lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a line containing a
>           group  separator  (--)  between  contiguous  groups  of  matches.   With  the   -o   or
>           --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
>
>    -C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
>           Print  NUM  lines  of  output context.  Places a line containing a group separator (--)
>           between contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this  has
>           no effect and a warning is given.
> ```

Comment: i found your answer interesting and different than that listed in "closed question linked above". The question recommended in closed question uses `grep -A20 "string_to_search" filename` whereas you're saying different way of doing that thing.